# Stax parser not parsing characters

Tags: java, xml, stax

I have an xml which has part like:

```
<BusinessEntity value="0">
<Name>
<Value locale="en">amd</Value>
</Name>
<UniqueFields>
<Field name="ID" value="0" />
</UniqueFields>
</BusinessEntity>
```

I am using stax parser, but when I set boolean value of BusinessEntity in START_ELEMENT and then I come to CHARACTERS the xmlStreamReader.getText() returns as null.

Characters:

```
 case XMLStreamConstants.CHARACTERS:                

                         //System.out.println(PriceName + "  " + xmlStreamReader.getText().trim());


                         if(BusinessEntity){

//                           System.out.println(Value + "  " + xmlStreamReader.getText().trim());
//                        XMLTag.setBusinessEntity(xmlStreamReader.getText().trim());
                                // System.out.println( "here " + xmlStreamReader.getText().trim() );
                            MapForTemp.put("BusinessEntity", xmlStreamReader.getText().trim());


                            BusinessEntity = false;
                        }
```

Start_ELEMENT :

```
if (xmlStreamReader.getLocalName().equals("BusinessEntity")) 
{

    BusinessEntity = true;
getAttributes(xmlStreamReader);

//int getAttribCount = xmlStreamReader .getAttributeCount();

}
```

getAttributes :

```
public static void getAttributes (XMLStreamReader xmlStreamReader){
      int AttributeCount =   xmlStreamReader.getAttributeCount();


      if (xmlStreamReader.getLocalName().equalsIgnoreCase("Price"))
      {
          if (xmlStreamReader.getAttributeLocalName(0).equals("id")){
                         priceguid = (xmlStreamReader.getAttributeValue(0));

          }

      }

      if (AttributeCount > 0)
      {                      
         StringBuilder stb = new StringBuilder();


         for (int m = 0; m < AttributeCount; m++)
         {

            stb.append(priceguid + " : " + xmlStreamReader.getLocalName() + " : " + xmlStreamReader.getAttributeLocalName(m));
             MapForAttributes.put(stb.toString().intern(), xmlStreamReader.getAttributeValue(m));
             stb.setLength(0);
         }

      }
      else {

          StringBuilder stb = new StringBuilder();
          stb.append(priceguid + " : " + xmlStreamReader.getLocalName() + " : " );
          MapForAttributes.put(stb.toString(), "null");
      }
}
```

Comment: Update your question with the actual code too

Comment: updated with actual code.